# Scheme (Swindle) -- How to access the value of a function

Tags: scheme

I have a function *f* that returns 1 or -1 depending on various conditions. This function is a parameter of another function. If I need to check if *f* evaluates to 1 or not, how can I do that? The code

```
(if (= f 1)
```

gives an error because it expects two numbers but was passed a function. How do I access the value of the function directly?

Answer (score 1):

`(if (= (f) 1) ... )`

Note the parentheses around `f`

If you need to keep track of that value, use

```
(let ((val (f)))
 (if (= val 1) ... ))
```